# Why passing null to an overloaded method causes a compiler error?

Tags: java, overloading

I have this code :

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
class D{
    public void m(B b){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    public void m(Object o){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    public void m(String s){
        System.out.println("C");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        D x = new D();
        x.m(null);
    }
}
```

I know this gives a compilation error. Compiler is confused among the results "A" and "C". Why null is extending from class B and String ?

Comment: `Why null is extending from class B and String ?` say whatt?

Comment: At a guess - just a guess, mind you - I'd say the compiler knows it can fall back on "B" if it knows that (for example) the argument were an `Integer`. But because it's `null`, it doesn't know if "A" or "C" are applicable. It knows B is applicable, but B is kind of the fallback option.

Comment: This topic is not new, there are tons of questions and posts explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

compiler is confused because you have three `m()` methods, and all of them can accept null reference. you need to explicitly tell which `m()` you want to call by casting the null to the desired argument like this `x.m((String)null);`

Comment: Actually, just two methods can be chosen

Comment: @SashaSalauyou the three of them can be chosen because all of them receive an object reference.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, only two--as there are two leaves in class hierarchy covering arguments (`String` and `B`). To prove this, create 3 overloaded methods, every of which accept child of another, say, `Object`, `CharSequence` and `String`--and you'll see no disambugation even when passing null (as one can guess, `String`-arg method will be selected for execution).